The answer is not wrong
If the answer is not wrong, then what is the answer?



4th
2nd
3rd
4th
4th













I like the, almost meta, puzzle and the answer given very much because it is something some people (certainly me) experience every so now and then in daily life conversations :-)

If an answer is not wrong, it’s right

@FirstNameLastName your daily life must be very different from mine.

Surely "not wrong" is the answer because the answer is not wrong. :)

Each of these images clues

 a compound word - namely: SNOWBOARD, TREADMILL, SPOTLIGHT, GRANDFATHER, and SONGWRITING.

If we

 index into these words via the numbers above them - we get W, R, O, N, and G - but wait, the answer is not WRONG!

So what is it? If we instead

 index into the second halves of these words using the same number, we get R, I, G, H, and T - that must be RIGHT!


Very fast! And of course correct :)
